# Problem connecting to Jetty (Timeout) and Java

Tags: java, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I would like to establish a connection to the Jetty server. The user is asked for the server address. Enter the address and then his name. I receive one Connect Timeout. The server is running. Does somebody has any idea?

I have three classes. ChatServer, ChatClient and ChatWebSocket. I use VSCode and Maven

```
package de.patternframe.model;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.websocket.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

@ClientEndpoint
public class ChatServer {

    private Session session;

    public void start(String address) {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        String uri = "ws://" + address + "/";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            container.connectToServer(this, new URI(uri));
            System.out.println("Connected to server " + uri);
            this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(username);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Disconnected ... " + session.getId());
        this.session = null;
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("Error ... " + session.getId());
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        if (this.session != null) {
            this.session = null;
        }
    }
    



    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(message);
            String userName = (String) json.get("username");
            String chatMessage = (String) json.get("message");

            String timestamp = new Date().toString();
            String formattedMessage = String.format("[%s] %s: %s\n", timestamp, userName, chatMessage);

            if (this.session.isOpen()) {
                this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(formattedMessage);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter server address: ");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        ChatServer server = new ChatServer();
        server.start(address);
    }
    

}
```

```
package de.patternframe.model;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class ChatClient {

    private static String SERVER_URI = "ws://localhost:8080/";
    private static ChatWebSocket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
        socket = new ChatWebSocket();
        
        try {
            client.start();
            URI serverUri = new URI(SERVER_URI);
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            client.connect(socket, serverUri, request);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
            String username = scanner.nextLine();
            socket.setUsername(username);
            System.out.println("Connection established with server " + SERVER_URI);
            while (true) {
                JSONObject jsonMessage = getMessage();
                socket.sendMessage(jsonMessage);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static JSONObject getMessage() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
        String message = scanner.nextLine();
        JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject();
        jsonMessage.put("type", "chat");
        jsonMessage.put("message", message);
        return jsonMessage;
    }
}
```

```
package de.patternframe.model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

@WebSocket
public class ChatWebSocket {
    private String username;
    private Session session;
    private static Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

    @OnWebSocketConnect
public void onConnect(Session session) throws IOException {
    this.session = session;
    sessions.add(session);
    this.session.getRemote().sendString("Connection established.");

    // Send the username to the server
    JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject();
    jsonMessage.put("type", "username");
    jsonMessage.put("username", this.username);
    session.getRemote().sendString(jsonMessage.toJSONString());
}


    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("Connection closed with statusCode=" + statusCode + ", reason=" + reason);
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonMessage = (JSONObject) parser.parse(message);
            String messageType = (String) jsonMessage.get("type");

            switch (messageType) {
                case "username":
                    this.username = (String) jsonMessage.get("username");
                    break;
                case "chat":
                    // Broadcast the chat message to all connected clients
                    broadcastMessage(this.username + ": " + jsonMessage.get("message"));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid message type.");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Error parsing JSON message.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(JSONObject jsonMessage) throws IOException {
        this.session.getRemote().sendString(jsonMessage.toJSONString());
    }
    
    private static void broadcastMessage(String message) {
        for (Session session : sessions) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                try {
                    session.getRemote().sendString(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject();
            jsonMessage.put("type", "username");
            jsonMessage.put("username", username);
            try {
                session.getRemote().sendString(jsonMessage.toJSONString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error setting username.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Session is null or closed. Cannot set username.");
        }
    }
}
```

```
pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.patternframe</groupId>
    <artifactId>loginregisterchat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
              <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
             <version>2.10.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
  <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
  <artifactId>tyrus-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax-websocket-client-impl</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>de.patternframe.model.ChatServer</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: English only on this edition of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your client is using the Jetty WebSocket API just fine.  The server seems to be wanting to use the JakartaEE WebSocket API for server, but isn't doing it properly?  How do you want it to function (normal Jetty WebSocket Server API, or Jakarta WebSocket Server running on Jetty)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server (I'll use the Jetty `Server`) and then
setup a server websocket endpoint to respond at a specific url.

The order is ...

1. `Server` the main server instance
2. `ServerConnector` to listen on specific ports
3. `ServletContextHandler` to have a context to map things to (like `/app`)
4. Mapping of url pattern to WebSocket endpoint
5. WebSocket open negotiation (sub-protocol, extensions, origin, etc)
6. WebSocket endpoint instance
7. Exchange of WebSocket frames (data / text / binary)

For steps 4 thru 7 there are 2 main choices of technology

1. Jetty WebSocket API
2. Jakarta EE WebSocket API

For steps 1 thru 3 there is little to no difference in technology choices.

There are a few examples of these choices that can be found
at the demo projects put together by the Eclipse Jetty Project at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples

Note: each `Main.java` is the `Server` and setup.

### Jetty WebSocket API techniques

- [`org/eclipse/jetty/demo/adapter/`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples/tree/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/adapter/) - using `addServlet()` to specify that `/echo` should map to `EchoServlet` which declares the endpoint `EchoSocket` which `extends WebSocketAdapter`
- [`org/eclipse/jetty/demo/annotated/`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples/tree/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/annotated/) - using `addServlet()` to specify that `/echo` should map to `EchoSocketServlet` which declares the endpoint `EchoSocket` which uses the `@WebSocket` annotation
- [`org/eclipse/jetty/demo/listener/`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples/tree/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/listener/) - using `addServlet()` to specify that `/echo` should map to `EchoSocketServlet` which declares the endpoint `EchoSocket` which `implements WebSocketListener`

### Jakarta WebSocket API techniques

- [`org/eclipse/jetty/demo/jsr/endpoint/`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples/tree/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/jsr/endpoint/) - using `JavaxWebSocketServletContainerInitializer` and `ServerEndpointConfig` to specify that `/echo` should map to `EchoSocket` which `extends Endpoint` and `implements MessageHandler.Whole<String>`
- [`org/eclipse/jetty/demo/jsr/annotated/`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples/tree/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/jsr/annotated/) - using `JavaxWebSocketServletContainerInitializer` and `container.addEndpoint()` to add endpoint `EchoSocket` which uses an annotation `@ServerEndpoint("/echo")` to map the endpoint to `/echo`